Why doesn't svg scale to 100% width of parent container with an explicit width on the svg
Why doesn't my svg scale to the size of its container when there is an explicit width and height on the svg? I can see that the svg styles are overwritten in the dev tools, but it doesn't seem to do anything.
I understand that I can remove the width and the height of the svg to make it scale, but I am interested why it doesn't work with the css overwrite.
example case:


div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
<div>
  <svg width="300" height="130" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="300" height="130" x="0" y="0" rx="20" ry="20" fill="blue" />
  </svg>
</div>




the svg is taking full width but the rect inside is not (add background-color to svg)

you are probably looking for viewBox (try viewBox="0 0 300 130")
